# Installing a carousel NPM module with CSS and JS generate code unrecognized by browser

Tags: javascript, npm, require

I am using this project as an excuse to familiarize myself with npm

I am using the bulma css framework to try to do a static website :

https://github.com/jgthms/bulma

I have installed bulma-start and cloned it to have a clean bulma project. npm start and http-server are running at the root of my folder. Every time I save, npm refresh the JS or the CSS depending what is needed. The local server allow me to have absolute URL working correctly during dev.

I tried to install [bulma-carousel](https://demo.creativebulma.net/components/carousel//#content). (I do not understand why the documentation is using ~ fot the paths, it seems weird to have the npm module sitting at the root of the home directory.)

First the CSS :

`@import "../node_modules/bulma-carousel/src/sass/index.sass";` was added and css/main.css is correctly generated with the carousel CSS rules.

However when I import the JS :
`import bulmaCarousel from '../node_modules/bulma-carousel/dist/jsbulma-carousel.min.js';`

It generate :

```
var _jsbulmaCarouselMin = require('../node_modules/bulma-carouse/dist/jsbulma-carousel.min.js');

var _jsbulmaCarouselMin2 = _interopRequireDefault(_jsbulmaCarouselMin);

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }
```

And require trigger the following error in the browser :

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

What should I do to properly import it ?